# Почему выдаётся ошибка при установке PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, pycharm

Когда я записал в терминал PyCharm команду: "pip3 install pyqt5", выдало такую ошибку:

Command "C:\Users\Zahar\PycharmProjects\training\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\Zahar\PycharmProjects\training\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.7.egg\pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix C:\Users\C25A~1\AppData\Loca
l\Temp\pip-build-env-lh_2tj0d\overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- "sip >=6.4, <7" "PyQt-builder >=1.9, <2"" failed with error code 1 in None

Answer (score 0):

В **PyCharm** создайте терминал во вкладке **"Terminal"** в нижней панели инструментов. далее перейдите по пути **venv\Scripts**. И напишите следующую команду:

```
# Если используется PowerShell
.\python.exe -m pip install pyqt5

# Если используется CMD
python.exe -m pip install pyqt5
```

И еще. Я заметил, что в проекте имеется виртуальная среда (venv). Так вот, в PyCharm есть вкладка для установки туда пакетов - **Python Packages**. Она находиться там же, где и вкладка с терминалом. Ниже скриншот:

> [image: Вкладка Python Packages в PyCharm.]
> Вкладка Python Packages в PyCharm.

Там вы можете устанавливать пакеты из репозиториев PyPI. Попробуйте также установить через нее, может поможет.

Comment: Можно уточнить, где именно переходить по пути venv/Scripts ?

Comment: У меня выводится синтаксическая ошибка: 

>>> python.exe -m pip install pyqt5
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python.exe -m pip install pyqt5
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Путь venv\Scripts находиться в папке с вашим проектом. Если вы создавали с виртуальной средой то в корневой папке проекта будет автоматически создана папка venv. Туда вам и нужно.

UPD:  Запускать python.exe вам нужно через командную строку или PowerShell, не запуская сам exe файл.

Comment: Я всё ещё пытался установить PyQt5, но всё равно выводится ошибка